# how to implement materialize navbar with angular 8

Tags: angular, materialize

I am new to angular and I have added materialize framework to my angular application by

```
npm install materialize-css --save 
npm install jquery --save
npm install --save hammerjs
```

my question is how can I implement materialize navbar in angular? what I have tried until now is:

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
  });

</script>
```

but it does not work, I have also tried jquery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();

    });
  </script>
```

Comment: If you're using Angular you don't need Materialize, you can just use Material https://material.angular.io/

Comment: what should I do for css? @nullptr.t

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would suggest to use [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/).**

In the [components](https://material.angular.io/components/categories) section you can find several material components like the [menu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) which can be used as main nav bar.

A minimal example would look like this:

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Help</button>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Have a look at the examples for Menu to get some ideas:

https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples

Additionally you can make use of several starter repos to see how Angular works together with Material e.g. [angular-ngrx-material-starter](http://%20https://github.com/tomastrajan/angular-ngrx-material-starter)

---

If you insist to use to use [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html) can make use of 'AfterViewInit' of angular to initialize elements. In your 'ts' file, implement 'AfterViewInit' and override ngAfterViewInit() method. Then write your initialization code inside setTimeout() function inside ngAfterViewInit().

```
export class NameComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ....

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout( function() {
      var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
      var instance = M.Sidenav.init(elem, options);
    }, 0)
  }

  .....

}
```

Comment: if I use angular material, what should I do for css? I mean with the classes that materialize offers

Comment: Guide for theming in Angular: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming | 
Customizing component styles: https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles